# Comparing voice input with existing audio sources

Tags: audio, spectrum

I'm currently working on creating a recipe for a script that would compare audio input with existing audio sources and return a match is any.

The idea is that the voice input would not be convertible to text. Those would be vocals such as dog ("woof") or cat ("meow") sound inputs.

In the end, I would like the script to conclude whether the input was a cat or dog sound, or none of the two.

I understand that It would require to pre process the sound input (low-pass; noise reduction etc), then do a spectrum analysis of the sound before comparing this to the existing spectrum analysis from the DB but I don't know where to start.

1. Are there any libraries for this kind of small project that could help?
2. How do I compare spectrum analysis?
3. How does spectrum analysis comparison take into account the possibility that two different people could make the same meow sound? Does it take into account a match up to a specific pourcentage?

Thanks for any guidance regarding this matter.

Comment: This sort of thing is actually a really big area of current research. Essentially, it turns out that it is very hard to figure out just what makes a bark sound a bark, and what properties of a sound are the most useful for doing so. Direct spectral comparison usually isn't the result taken, as things that sound similar can have spectrums that differ more than you'd think. It also brings up the problem of alignment -- the sounds have to be the same length and their starts have to be aligned.

Comment: Here are two possibly relevant links: http://www.nyu.edu/classes/bello/ACA_files/8-classification.pdf, https://aqibsaeed.github.io/2016-09-03-urban-sound-classification-part-1/